# quick folder access on Linux (akin to Launchy)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, productivity

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) is a great piece of software, I use it on Windows mainly for quickly accessing folders. I love its auto-indexing in the background, and hardly ever browse through folders manually these days, solves me lots of time.

On Linux (Ubuntu 9.10), I usually "live" in the terminal, however. Therefore, Launchy on Linux (or Gnome Do, or its other replacements) are not what I need - as it opens the file manager, and I don't need the file manager.

What I do need is something that indexes my folders and lets me `cd` into them quickly in the terminal. For example:

```
mycd python_c
```

Will `cd` to:

```
~/dev/scripts/python_code
```

I hope my intention is understood :-)

Are you familiar with such tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to write down that after some looking around I've found [z](http://github.com/rupa/z) - it learns the directories you CD into and then lets you easily jump into them.

There's also [autojump](http://wiki.github.com/joelthelion/autojump/), but `z` appears to be closer to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has the `CDPATH` variable.

```
$ CDPATH="$CDPATH:~/dev/scripts/:/some/other/one/too"
$ cd python_code
/home/username/dev/scripts/python_code
$ pwd
/home/username/dev/scripts/python_code
```

You could script the maintenance of the value something like this:

In your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cd() {
    while read -r dir
    do
        if [[ ! $CDPATH =~ $dir ]]
        then
            CDPATH="${CDPATH}:${dir}"
        fi
    done < ~/.cdpath
    builtin cd "$@"
}
cd .    # update CDPATH
export CDPATH
```

In a file called `/usr/local/bin/mkcdpath`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# update the stored CDPATH directory list
# run from cron, can be run manually
# requires Bash >= 3.2
cdp=$(<~/.cdpath)
while read -r dir
do
    if [[ ! $cdp =~ $dir ]]
    then
        cdp="${cdp}:${dir}"
    fi
done < <(find /anchored_at_root -maxdepth 1 some_find_args  -type d)
echo "$cdp" > ~/.cdpath
```

Run that periodically using `cron`.

Now anytime you use `cd`, it will update the current shell's `CDPATH` and perform the directory change according to it (in addition to doing normal `cd`s which are tried first). You could change the function name (and remove the `cd` command) to make it an update function only and use the regular cd command - it just wouldn't update the value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in some [advanced feature of `zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html#l33). It add some extra shortcuts to `cd`.